# java.net.SocketException: Operation not permitted

Tags: android, sip, udpclient

Code:

```
final int port = 5060;
byte[] inviteBytes = sipInvite.getBytes();
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(inviteBytes, inviteBytes.length, toInetAddress, port);
DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
serverSocket.send(packet);
```

Which throws:

```
09-10 19:18:00.107: WARN/System.err(5408): java.net.SocketException: Operation not permitted
09-10 19:18:00.117: WARN/System.err(5408):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.sendDatagramImpl(Native Method)
09-10 19:18:00.117: WARN/System.err(5408):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.sendDatagram(OSNetworkSystem.java: 571)
09-10 19:18:00.117: WARN/System.err(5408):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java: 275)
09-10 19:18:00.117: WARN/System.err(5408):   at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:463)
09-10 19:18:00.117: WARN/System.err(5408):   at com.icast.mypie.sip.SipClient.doConnect(SipClient.java:71)
09-10 19:18:00.117: WARN/System.err(5408):   at com.icast.mypie.sip.SipClient.run(SipClient.java:43)
```

Nexus 2.2, device connects via wifi. Port not blocked. Datagram send works from android 1.5 moto blur.

Comment: (a) Please format your code next time. (b) What's the question?

Comment: 1) sure.Question: Why would one get Operation

Comment: 2) Why would one get operation not permitted error ? What can be done to resolve it ?

Comment: Did you set the right permissions for you APP to acess the internet?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending the bytes of the SIPmessage, try sending some random bytes through the DatagramSocket at the same place in the code, this should work (Only to verify the problem)

I couldn't send a SIPmessage in my program, too and it turned out that there was a problem with the SDP-payload in the SIPMessage, especially with blanks in some places.

The SIPMessage with SDP payload could get send through the emulator (2.2 & 2.3.3), but couln't get send by my G1 and the Nexus S (with Android 2.3.3 and Android 2.3.4).

The exact reason why the DatagramSocket does behave like is still not clear, but I'll keep on with it.